# `parbox=false` makes `before skip` fail when a tcolorbox is nested in another

Tags: tcolorbox

Here is a MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\tcbset{
  testin/.style = {
    parbox = false,
    before skip = 20pt,    % I changed 'before skip' but it doesn't work.
  }
}


\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[testin]
  \lipsum[1-2]
  \tcblower
  test
  \begin{tcolorbox}[testin]
    testin
  \end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[testin]
  testin
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

I found `parbox = false` would make the `before skip = 20pt` fail. Also, the text and the tcolorbox nested would "glue together" like this:
[image]

But I want the text above to have the correct indent, like this:
[image]
If there was no `parbox = false`, I couldn't make the correct indent.
I wonder if there is a way to solve it?

Comment: This is a `tcolorbox` bug (since v4.40), and I've reported in https://github.com/T-F-S/tcolorbox/issues/171. Also a workaround is given there.

Comment: I would think that nesting tcolorbox is like nesting tikzpicture; sometimes it works, but don't count on it.

Comment: See the [tcolorbox, issues171](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/634581/parbox-false-makes-before-skip-fail-when-a-tcolorbox-is-nested-in-another?noredirect=1#:~:text=See%20the-,tcolorbox%2C%20issues171,-for%20the%20solution) for a solution by T-F-S.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a bug already reported.